# Is it possible to change a scrollbar with my own image?

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to change a scrollbar with my own image?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: url('MY IMAGE');
}
```

Comment: it will not work in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only chrome will support it.
You can remove the scrollbar and use a custom, jQuery one like the following:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/